# Unable to resolve dependency firebase and google play service

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to connect my android project to firebase. It was working also properly in starting. I don't know what happened all by sudden i am got series of Unresolved dependencies.

I have done almost all steps which I found over web. Like disable offline work, Invalidate chache/restart. Even when I am creating new project I am facing same problem. Earlier this all things were not happening.

My application gradle code is :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

      }
    }

     allprojects {
       repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
        jcenter()
      }
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

build.gradle for module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
       compileSdkVersion 28
       defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aabsys.metasensing"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    }

     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks in advance.[Please find image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3uOi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following dependency in your code:-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

If it still does not resolve your issue, try updating Google play services and Google repository.[image]

Comment: What error is coming exactly. The image doesn't show the actual error.

Comment: after adding `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`  its showing error as Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4.

Comment: try updating your google play services and google repository

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the class path

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by reducing google service version to :

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'`

And removing

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`